# how to make material data grid width to fill the parent component in react js

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I'm trying to display the data grid with all columns should take equal width to fit the parent component. but there is a blank space at the end which I'm not able to remove and cannot make columns to take auto width to fit page width.

can anyone please help me on this

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-montalcini-tn04y

[image]

Comment: Give flex value for each column - https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-https-7pp93?file=/src/App.js:554-561

Comment: @SarunUK please add this as answer. It's working like charm

Comment: what does flex: val do? please explain what that means.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Include flex value for each column level like below,

```
const columns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", flex: 1 },
  { field: "firstName", headerName: "First name", flex: 1 },
  { field: "lastName", headerName: "Last name", flex: 1 },
  {
    field: "age",
    headerName: "Age",
    type: "number",
    flex: 1
  },
  {
    field: "fullName",
    headerName: "Full name",
    description: "This column has a value getter and is not sortable.",
    sortable: false,
    flex: 1,
    valueGetter: (params) =>
      `${params.getValue(params.id, "firstName") || ""} ${
        params.getValue(params.id, "lastName") || ""
      }`
  }
];
```

codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-https-7pp93?file=/src/App.js:266-850

Comment: can you please add what that means? what does flex:1 do?. what does flex do? It's just not clear from your answer. thx

Comment: @MattoMK That would be an unrelated topic, if you are curious about what this does, try these resources instead:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and https://flexboxfroggy.com/ to practice.

Comment: @DaveFunk's recommendation pertains to CSS flexbox properties in general. While useful to know, flexbox is only tangentially related to the 'flex' property of the MUI data grid column definition. A more specific answer to that question may be found here: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-dimensions/#fluid-width.

Comment: They become same width in that case. How would I make it adjust according to column's content width

Comment: This should totally be on the documentation page

Comment: This should be the default. Maybe it's in the paid version? ;-)

Answer (score 34):

in my case, I include flex as well as minWidth property which helps the table show full data in **SM (small)** and **(XS) extra small** devices.

```
const columns = [
    {field: "id", hide: true},
    {field: "transaction", headerName: "Transactions", minWidth: 330, flex: 1},
    {field: "date", headerName: "Date", minWidth: 100, flex: 1},
    {field: "type", headerName: "Type", minWidth: 100, flex: 1},
    {field: "price", headerName: "Price", minWidth: 110, flex: 1},
    {field: "gas", headerName: "Gas", minWidth: 110, flex: 1},
    {field: "total", headerName: "Total", minWidth: 110, flex: 1} ]
```

Comment: Setting minWidth helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Setting a min width will also ensure your table headings do not truncate when using flex 1 when compressing, but will always fill available space.

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex` and `minWidth` make the dataGrid flicker on page loading.
It looks like it is rendered multiple times.